# spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb doesn't seem to include persistence-api to use @PrePersist @PreUpdate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-boot-starter

What is the correct way to include and use `JPA Entity Lifecycle Events` when using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb?

my pom.xml dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

My classpath doesn't see to have any of the following JPA annotations:

```
@PrePersist
@PostPersist
@PreRemove
@PostRemove
@PreUpdate
@PostUpdate
@PostLoad
```

Comment: And why should it include a JPA dependency? JPA has nothing to do with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo has its own events documented @ [#Entity Callbacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#entity-callbacks).

Example:

```
class DefaultingEntityCallback implements BeforeSaveCallback<Person>, Ordered {      

    @Override
    public Object onBeforeSave(Person entity, String collection) {                   

        if(collection == "user") {
            return // ...
        }

        return // ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 100;                                                                  
    }
}
```

Following Functional interfaces available:

- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterConvertCallback
- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterSaveCallback
- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.BeforeConvertCallback
- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.BeforeSaveCallback
- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ReactiveAfterConvertCallback
- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ReactiveAfterSaveCallback
- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ReactiveBeforeConvertCallback
- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ReactiveBeforeSaveCallback